# Redirect Apache SSL traffic to subdomain with a proper certificate

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, https, dynamic-dns

I currently have a server which has a DynDNS subdomain (let's call it foo.dyn.com).  I also have a proper domain with a CNAME pointing to that subdomain (let's call it bar.baz.com).  foo.dyn.com has a self-signed SSL certificate, while bar.baz.com has a proper CA-signed SSL certificate.

I've set up Apache to redirect non-ssl requests for either domain to `https://bar.baz.com`, which works fine.
My problem is this: I want anyone trying to access `https://foo.dyn.com` to get redirected to `https://bar.baz.com`.  I've tried 2 solutions and neither get it quite right:

1. Have 1 VirtualHost, using the CA certificate.  This obvious gives a horrible warning about domain using the wrong certificate when someone tries to access `https://foo.dyn.com`.
2. Have 2 VirtualHosts, one for foo.dyn.com with the self-signed certificate and one for bar.baz.com using the proper certificate.  The foo.dyn.com has a redirect clause that redirects all traffic to `https://bar.baz.com`, which works except that you still the the self-signed certificate warning.  Also, some non-web browser HTTP clients (like wget) get foo.dyn.com's certificate when pointed at bar.baz.com

Is there a way I can get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem in the protocol stack. You can only have one SSL certificate per IP per Port.

The reason is the following:
The VirtualHost system of apache and alike is based on the [HTTP Host Header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.23). However, this header is sent after the SSL connection is established (as all headers are sent after establishing the SSL connection, otherwise it would be a bit of useless).

So, the only means the server has to choose a certificate are based on the interface or IP the connection is incoming on and the port.

A solution for the warning would be though to add your second domain as SubjectAltName to the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Server Name Indication, if your clients support it. (See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8538028/372643) for links.)